# APNS with PHP shows SSL broken pipe error

Tags: php, ssl, apple-push-notifications

In my project there is around 500 iOS users.Sending push notification to them shows the following error.

```
Severity: Warning
Message:  fwrite(): SSL: Broken pipe
Message:  fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1409F07F:SSL routines:ssl3_write_pending:bad write retry
```

Upto some tokens works correct,results integers eg.181, since from the first token which result 0 shows the above mentioned error.Is it due to invalid tokens ?.I cann't differentiate production and development tokens.Please help.Thanks in advance.
My code

```
public function connectApns(){

            try{

                $ctx = stream_context_create();
                stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/webservice/application/libraries/ck.pem');
                stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl','passphrase', '1234');
                $this->fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);


                    if($this->fp){
                        return TRUE;
                    }else{
                        echo $errstr;
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                }
            catch(Exception $e1){

                echo $e1->getMessage();

            }

        }

    public function iOS($data,$columnName){

            $ids = array();
            $tokens = array();
            $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM tp_notification WHERE ";
            if($columnName == "job"){
               $sql = $sql." job = 1"; 
            }
            if($columnName == "hostel"){
                $sql = $sql." hostel = 1";
            }
            if($columnName == "event"){
                $sql = $sql." event = 1";
            }
            if($columnName == "bazar"){
                $sql = $sql." bazar = 1";    
            }
            if($columnName == "share"){
                $sql = $sql." share = 1"; 
            }
            if($columnName == "court"){
                $sql = $sql." court = 1";
            }
            if($columnName == "contest"){
                $sql = $sql." contest = 1";
            }
            if($columnName == ""){

                $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM tp_notification";
            }
            $query = $this->CI->db->query($sql);
            if($query){
                $mid_result = $query->result_array();
                foreach ($mid_result as $value)
                {
                    $ids[] = $value['user_id'];
                }
                if(count($ids) > 0){
                    $sql1 = "SELECT device_token FROM tp_user WHERE user_id IN ? AND device_type = ? AND user_active = ? ORDER BY user_id DESC";
                    $query1 = $this->CI->db->query($sql1,array($ids,'iOS',1));
                    if($query1){
                        $mid_result1 = $query1->result_array();
                        foreach ($mid_result1 as $key)
                        {
                            $tokens[] = $key['device_token'];
                        } 
                    }   
                }
            }


            if(count($tokens) > 0){

                $isConnected = $this->connectApns();

                if ($isConnected){
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($tokens); $i++){


                        $sql5 = "SELECT badge FROM tp_user WHERE device_token = ?";
                        $query5 = $this->CI->db->query($sql5,array($tokens[$i]));
                        $badge = 0;
                        if($query5){
                            $mid_result5 = $query5->row();
                            $badge = $mid_result5->badge + 1;
                        }
                        $body['aps'] = array(
                                        'alert' => array(
                                        'title' => $data['title'],
                                        'body' => $data['data'],
                                        'type'=>$data['type'],
                                        'id'=>$data['id']
                                        ),
                                        'content-available'=>1,
                                        'badge'=>$badge,
                                        'sound' => 'default'
                                    );
                        $deviceToken = $tokens[$i];

                        $payload = json_encode($body);
                        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
                        try{    
                                                        if(strlen($deviceToken) == 64){



                                                              $result = fwrite($this->fp, $msg, strlen($msg));}





                            if($result){


                                $sql6 = "UPDATE tp_user SET badge=? WHERE device_token=?";
                                $query6 = $this->CI->db->query($sql6,array($badge,$tokens[$i]));

                               }else{

                                fclose($this->fp);  
                                sleep(5);
                                $this->connectApns();
                            }
                        } catch(Exception $e){

                            fclose($this->fp);  
                            sleep(3);
                            $this->connectApns();

                        }



                    }

                    fclose($this->fp);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Include code that is  relevant to your question.

Comment: My code is shown above

Answer (score 0):

Define the Constant

```
  define('Apple_HOST','gateway.push.apple.com');
  define('Apple_API_NOTI',"abc.pem");   // write here path  pem file
```

call the function ->

```
 sendPushIos("write here device token",array('alert' =>$message, 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default','flag'=>$flag))
```

ios Notification send function ->

```
                function sendPushIos($dEvicetoken,$arrayY){
                            $apnsHost = Apple_HOST;
                            $apnsCert =Apple_API_NOTI;
                            $apnsPort = 2195;
                            $token=$dEvicetoken;
                            $streamContext = stream_context_create();
                            @stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
                            $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
                            $payload['aps'] =$arrayY;
                            $output = json_encode($payload);
                            $token = pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token));
                            $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . $token . chr(0) . chr(strlen($output)) . $output;
                    if(fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage))
                    {
                        @socket_close($apns);
                        fclose($apns);
                         return TRUE;
                }else{
                        return FALSE;
                    }
 }
```

*Note: 2195 port must be opened*

Comment: Few notifications has sent,For those result is greater than 0, Then result changed to 0,then ssl broken pipe error shows.Is this problem related to SSL?

Comment: Now its working.I extended the if(strlen($deviceToken)) loop to before try 's closing bracket.ie to the last.